# Create records with other table values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two SQL tables, Users and Claims:

```
Users > Id (PK Identity), Name
Claims > Id (PK Identity), UserId (FK), Name, Value
```

I need to create a Claim with Name="Plan" and Value="XK" for all Users.

I got the Id of each User since it will be the UserId of a Claim:

```
SELECT Id
From Users;
```

Now for each Id I need to insert a Claim as:

```
Claim.UserId = User.Id
Claim.Name = "Plan"
Claim.Value = "XK"
```

Comment: Are you getting stuck.  This does seem a bit lowly question for someone with 5k points?  Is there something else - billions of records, locking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
insert into claims(userid, [name], [value])
select userid, 'plan', 'XK'
from users
left join claims
on users.id = claims.userid
where claims.userid is null
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Insert into Claims (userid, name, value)Select id, 'Plan','XK' from Users
```